# Is there currently a way to instantiate an internal class using .NET Standard?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

I have been looking for a solution to this for quite some time - considering how simple this should be. I have a library that targets `netstandard1.5` and `net451`. It is working fine in `net451`. There is one method in one class in the whole library that uses .NET Reflection to create an instance of a type with an internal constructor from another library (that also targets both `netstandard1.5` and `net451`).

But, it seems the overload I need of `Activator.CreateInstance` that accepts `BindingFlags`...

```
public static object CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
```

...is not available in `netstandard1.5` or even in `netstandard1.6`. I see that it [will be in `netstandard2.0`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/standard/master/docs/versions/netstandard2.0_diff.md), but that is not yet released.

I tried creating a Portable Class Library, but I can't seem to reference a dependent library that targets `netstandard1.5` from it. I just get the error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Package OtherPackage 3.1.0-beta00001 is not compatible with dotnet5.0 (.NETPlatform,Version=v5.0). Package OtherPackage 3.1.0-beta00001 supports:
    - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
    - netstandard1.5 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.5)
```

So, is there really NO current way to support .NET Core if you are using Reflection on internal members? If there is, how can it be done?

Comment: I know it can't always be done but why not just change it to be a `public` class if you need it outside the library? Or even why are you using it if it shouldn't be used outside the library?

Comment: 1) The internal constructor is in a different library. 2) The design is a port from Java and it creates a class in the same namespace as the other library, which seems to be enough in Java to be able to instantiate the class. There doesn't seem to be an alternative to using Reflection in .NET.

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance` isn't magic, at least not where regular .NET types are concerned. It's no more involved than getting the appropriate `ConstructorInfo` (`TypeInfo.GetConstructor`) and calling `Invoke` on that. I don't know the complete surface of `netstandard`, so I don't know if it supports reflection enough for this, but it's an alternative. That said, port from Java or not, this design isn't very good in .NET. Types that need each others `internal`s should be part of the same assembly, as they are explicitly coupled.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - I also looked into using `ConstructorInfo.Invoke`, but there is no way to pass `BindingFlags` to that either. The default behavior of `GetConstructor()` can only use a public constructor (but if it were public, I wouldn't need Reflection).

Comment: According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.typeinfo.getconstructors?view=netstandard-1.5), `TypeInfo.GetConstructors(BindingFlags)` (note the plural) is available in netstandard1.5.

Comment: Hmm...that is really strange. But I tested it and it works - I will accept it as an answer if no better alternative comes along.

Comment: It's not strange if you consider the fact that this method is the *minimum* support needed to get all constructors of a type. All the rest (like searching for a particular constructor) can be built on top of it. Making an API complete in principle has more priority than making it feature complete, including all convenience methods.

Comment: That makes sense. Could you please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Done. Used `DeclaredConstructors` of the new reflection API instead, which is both less cumbersome and slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `netstandard1.5` lacks the full trappings of reflection, the basics are available. Given a class `T` that has a parameterless constructor (regardless of visibility), this is how you dynamically construct an instance:

```
ConstructorInfo c = typeof(T)
    .GetTypeInfo()
    .DeclaredConstructors
    .Single(ci => ci.GetParameters().Length == 0)
;
T t = (T) c.Invoke(Type.EmptyTypes);
```

The call to `.Single()` is not strictly necessary if you know the type has only one constructor anyway (you could use `.First` instead, or leave out the predicate) but it's highly advisable to include it anyway, lest the code break if a constructor is added in the future.

Comment: Much better - no silly `BindingFlags`. The constructor has 6 arguments, so I ended up with `var constr = typeof(AtomicReaderContext).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredConstructors.Single(constructor => constructor.GetParameters().Select(parameter => parameter.ParameterType).SequenceEqual(constructorTypeArray));`.